# Swap two registers in aarch64

Tags: assembly, swap, arm64, micro-optimization

I'm learning AArch64 assembly.  Coming from x86 I found it interesting that there doesn't seem to be any single instruction like `xchg` to swap two registers.  Unless I'm mistaken, the `swp` instruction only swaps a register with memory (which is of course a much more important case due to atomicity).

There are a few obvious ways to do this, with various tradeoffs.  I'll use `x0, x1` as examples.

1. Using a scratch register: three instructions, one extra register.

```
mov x2, x0
mov x0, x1
mov x1, x2
```

2. Using the exclusive-or trick: three instructions, no extra register

```
eor x0, x0, x1
eor x1, x0, x1
eor x0, x0, x1
```

3. Using the stack: two instructions, no extra register, two 16-byte memory accesses:

```
stp x0, x1, [sp, -16]!
ldp x1, x0, [sp], 16
```

Are there any better approaches that I am missing?  "Better" could be any of: smaller code, faster code (on typical machines), fewer registers needed, less memory access, more idiomatic.

I'd also be interested in approaches that work for the SIMD/FP registers.

(I know this would be a silly thing to try to optimize in most cases; this is more just a way for me to learn about the instruction set than anything else.)

Comment: The usual way is via scratch register, at least that's what the compilers seem to choose and if your cpu supports register renaming that might turn out to be the most efficient anyway.

Comment: With #2, each of your instructions depends upon the result of the previous one, so they may not overlap; whereas with #1 the cpu can prepare #2 in parallel with #1,#3.  With such a small example and fast opcodes, it feels a bit silly; but C+P that sequence 500 times, then put it in a loop for a few million and let the clock tell you the answer.

Comment: Having learned some more about the architecture, the absence of a swap instruction makes more sense, as one of the principles of the instruction set is evidently that "no instruction shall write more than one register", with `ldp` and the writeback-indexing address modes being the only exceptions I've found.  It leads to some interesting contortions for multiplication and division.

Comment: Yeah, ARM had several instructions that wrote 2 regs, like `umull`, as well as NEON `vuzp` / `vzip` (like x86 punpckldq and hdq combined, writing both regs).  But AArch64 change those, too, to `zip1` / `zip2`  and `uzp1` / `uzp2` that write one reg each, matching x86-style `punpckl` / `h`.  https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2020-12/SIMD-FP-Instructions/ZIP1--Zip-vectors--primary--

Comment: Note that unlike in high level language code, swapping the contents of two registers in hand crafted assembly is not too common, Even if you move both away rare they'd both be the ideal register to move the others value to. Smells like an academic exercise.

Comment: @DavidPerek: It was definitely just an exercise, though one that I set for myself.  (Then again, I am an academic myself, so...)